# What's the relation between spin model for subfactors theory and physics?

Tags: mp.mathematical-physics, oa.operator-algebras, subfactors, ising-model

In the sense of [subfactor theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subfactor), a spin model is a commuting square of the form
$$\begin{matrix}
\Delta &\subset & M_n(\mathbb{C})\cr
\cup &\ &\cup\cr
\mathbb{C} &\subset &w\Delta w^*\end{matrix}$$
where $\Delta\subset M_n(\mathbb{C})$ is the algebra of diagonal matrices and
where $w\in M_n(\mathbb{C})$ is a [complex Hadamard matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_Hadamard_matrix), i.e. a unitary all
whose entries are of modulus $n^{-1/2}$ (*Source*: [this paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/9909156v2) of T. Banica. See also [JS](http://www.cambridge.org/us/knowledge/isbn/item1155032/?site_locale=en_US) chapter 6).

In the sense of physics, a spin model is  a mathematical model used to explain magnetism (see [its wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin_model)).

*Question*: What's the relation between them?

Answer (score 2):

I am not familiar with spin models in the sense of subfactors, but my guess is the link between the two is conformal quantum field theory. The scaling limit of a critical spin model (in the sense of physics) usually gives a CQFT. On the other hand there is also a correspondence between subfactors and CQFTs. I think there is work by Wassermann for constructing CQFTs out of subfactors. V. Jones also has some conjectures about all subfactors arising from CQFTs in some way.